# VBA formula for one column displaying as text?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to put in a VBA formula into column AC but the result is showing as text. I've tried clearing formats on that column. Following similar code, other columns are successfully showing formulas, so I'm not sure what's particular about this column. It's a simple IF ELSE statement using date fields.

Logic: if there is a value in column AB, return AB. If not, return from column W.

```
Dim row As Long
row = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

Worksheets("Data").Activate
Sheets("Data").Range("AC:AC").ClearFormats
Sheets("Data").Range("AC2:AC" & row ).Formula = "=IF(LEN(AB2) > 0, AB2, W2)"
```

Comment: 1) Fully qualify all range/sheet references by prefixing the workbook with a point separator, too; otherwise VBA assumes the currently active sheet in the active workbook. 2) You might profit from a `With ...` .. `End With` construction to minimize the full range references. 3) Provide for the case that there is no data in column "A"; Excel assumes a range start in row 1 though you want to start formula input in row 2 as a minimum row no. 4) Avoid `activate` and `select` if possible. 5) Tip: try to avoid a variable name like `row` as it is normally used as (range) property name .

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the code below in the sheet you want to copy the formula, don't need the name of worksheet, just use the keyword Me

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyFormula()
   Dim row As Long
   row = Me.Cells(rows.CountLarge, "A").End(xlUp).row
   
   With Me.Range("AC:AC")
      .ClearFormats
      '------------------------the next line is critical
      .NumberFormat = "General"
   End With
   Me.Range("AC2:AC" & row).Formula = "=IF(LEN(AB2) > 0, AB2, W2)"
End Sub
```